# change html text from link with prototype

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

a simple question here

Is there a way to change the text "click here"

```
<a id="a_tbnotesverbergen" href="#nothing">click here</a>
```

in this link using prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a_tbnotesverbergen").update("New Text")
```

This should do.